# Column in Pandas Series is appearing in a row above the rest

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display_html

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Mike','George', 'George']})
name_series = df.groupby("Name").size()   
name_series.name = ''
name_dataframe = name_series.to_frame()
name_styler = name_dataframe.style.set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'")

display_html(name_styler.render(), raw = True)
```

I have this cell where I want to display a DataFrame in this fashion so I can add more directly beside it to, rather than displaying DataFrames one after another.

When I display it with the name set to blank, the data looks like this:

[image]

When I set to name to anything, then it seems like the column name appears on the row above the rest of the table:

[image]

I checked my code posted in another website and the tables all look like this if I don't set a name to a column, which means there's another row being created for some reason:

[image]

How can I place the new column name and the existing column name on the same row?

edit:
After applying `name_dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True)`

[image]

edit 2:
Applying `name_series.index.name=None` gives:

[image]

Is there a way to combine answers to just show both titles and columns ONLY, "Name" and "Count" ?

Comment: df.reset_index(inplace=True)

Comment: Your series is named Count, and your Index is named Name, so that's how it displays both names. You can set `ser.index.name=None`

Comment: Am I supposed to do that right after I define df? Because that's not working @wwnde

Comment: @wwnde Oh unless you meant name_series.reset_index(inplace=True) ? Because that worked for me, now if I want to place my tables together, I don't want the new "0" "1" beside all my tables, do you know how to remove that? I'll make an edit of what it looks like

Comment: @G.Anderson So your comment actually helped too, it got rid of the Name title though, is there some way to combine both your answers so that all I'm left with is the "Name" and "Count" with both titles? I'll make an edit (I also deleted a previous comment, I made a mistake in case you're wondering)